# What is the fastest / recommended way of creating new list with duplicate list entries in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

My values naturally come in this form:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

I am developing against a server api which requires an input parameter like:

```
[1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8,9,9]
```

Is there a faster or more js-style way to do than a simple for loop?

```
var f = function(values) {
    var newList = [];
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
         newList.push(values[i]);
         newList.push(values[i]);
    }
    return newList;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could avoid a `.push()` call by combining them since `.push()` is variadic.

```
 newList.push(values[i], values[i]);
```

Other than that, I doubt you'll get much quicker.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `each` function.

this will reduce your step.

```
var list=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
var newlist=[];
$.each(list,function(index,data){newlist.push(data);newlist.push(data)})
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Function calls are relatively expensive. That'll be slower. And jQuery *(I assume that's what you're using)* isn't needed for this, and you don't know if OP is using it.

Answer (score 1):

Try: `[].concat.call([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]).sort();`

or more generic:

```
(function(){
   return this.concat(this).sort(function(a,b){return a-b;});}
).call([1,2,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,9]);
```

or just a function:

```
function(v) {
    var i = v.length, nw = [];
    while (i--) { nw.push(v[i],v[i]); }
    return nw.reverse();
}
```

or using `map`

```
var nw = ([1,2,3,4,5].map(function(a){this.push(a,a)},nw=[]),nw);
```

I suspect the function is the most efficient.

Answer (score 1):

May be assignment is faster...

```
L2 = [];
for (var i=L1.lenght*2; i-->0;) {
    L2[i>>1] = L1[i];
}
```

but this kind of micro-optimization really needs to be profiled on the specific implementations (and I wouldn't be surprised in big differences between different Javascript engines).

I'd keep the most readable way unless this is a key issue (and if it's a key issue they probably Javascript is the wrong tool).